# Nesting MUI tree with custom components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm very new to the React and Javascript world, and I'm trying to understand why my code isn't working/behaving the way it does, and what the better way to achieve it is. Basically, I'm trying to create a tree, using a custom component as branches. When I run my code though, child objects don't seem to display properly.

I'm using tree items from the MUI library. I have a custom component (RomItem, as follows) that I was using to create the branches, so that I could pass some additional properties I'll be using for some backend stuff later on. In essence, each branch of the tree will have a bunch of data properties that will later be populated by a form, and then the tree (loaded with data) will be sent to my backend for other duties.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { TreeItem, TreeView } from '@mui/lab'

function RomItem(props){
    const nodeId = props.nodeId
    const label = props.label
    const type = props.type
    return (
        <TreeItem 
            nodeId = {props.nodeId}
            label = {props.label}
            type = {props.type}>
        </TreeItem> 

    

  );
}
export default RomItem;
```

When I call the custom component (in RomTree.js, as follows). The behavior isn't what I'd expect. As my code is written, I only see the parent item when running. If I change the outermost RomItem tag to TreeItem, it works as intended. It does not work as intended if I make the child RomItem tag a TreeItem.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import RomItem from './RomItem'
import { TreeItem, TreeView } from '@mui/lab'

function RomTree(props){
    function onClickHandler(event){

    };

    return(
            <div>
            <TreeView
                aria-label="file system navigator"
                sx={{ height: 240, flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, overflowY: 'auto' }}>
                    <RomItem
                        nodeId = {props.nodeId}
                        label = {props.label}
                        type = {props.type}>
                            <RomItem 
                                nodeId = {'2'}
                                label = {'A Child Epic'}
                                type = {props.type}>
                            </RomItem>
                    </RomItem>
                    
            </TreeView>
            <button onClick= {onClickHandler}></button>    
            </div>            
    );
}

export default RomTree;
```

And for completeness, my App.js code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import RomItem from './components/RomItem'
import RomTree from './components/RomTree'

function App(){
  const initROMItems = [
    {
      nodeId: 'root',
      label: 'New Epic',
      type: 'Epic'
    }
  ];

  return (
    
    <div className="App">
      <div>Rom Panel4</div>
        <RomTree 
          nodeId = {initROMItems[0].nodeId}
          label = {initROMItems[0].label}
          type = {initROMItems[0].type}
        ></RomTree>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Other than what I need to do to make this work, am I going about this the wrong way? I thought to use state to handle the values that will eventually be sent to the backend, but given that my code as is isn't working, I wasn't sure if that would work. It would make more sense for me to create a child class to TreeItem from the MUI library that has all the parameters I'll be getting, but as I understand it, that's a bit obsolete/frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get children from props - this way nested RomItem inside RomItem will appear:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { TreeItem, TreeView } from '@mui/lab'

export function RomItem({ nodeId, label, type, children }) {
    return (
        <TreeItem nodeId={nodeId} label={label} type={type}>
            {children}
        </TreeItem>
    )
}

export default RomItem;
```

Comment: By the way if you use typescript in your project typescript compiler will complain on  code you provided  - `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RomItemProps'.`